# infinite dimensional normed space is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that space X with norm of sum is  not complete.
for any x, we have $x= \sum^n_{k=1}c_{k}b_k$ where $b_k\in basis$  and $c_k\in field$

norm is $\lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert = $ $\sum^n_{k=1}\lvert c_k\rvert$

for example, if I take $c_k=\frac{1}{k^2}$ and $x_{N}=\sum^N_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}b_k$, this will converge to $\sum^{\infty}_1\frac{1}{k^2}b_k$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$.

Aslo $\lvert\lvert x_N - x_M\rvert\rvert\le \sum^M_{k=N+1}\frac{1}{k^2} \lt\epsilon$, so it is Cauchy.

Here I am not sure why $\| b_k\|=1$ and why $\sum^{\infty}_1\frac{1}{k^2}b_k$ is not in X.

Could you please help me with my questions.

Comment: For your argument, $\lVert b_{k}\rVert < k^{2}$ is necessary. Ex ante you can not be sure about it but given the basis, you can always look at $\hat{b}_{k}:=\frac{1}{\lVert b_{k}\rVert}b_{k}$. Regarding your question of incompleteness, I guess it arises because the limit ought to be a finite linear combination. So you check that it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $b_k$ is in the basis, the only way to write $b_k$ as a (finite) linear combination of the elements of the basis is $b_k=b_k$, so $\Vert b_k\Vert= 1$ for all $k$. The series $\sum\frac{b_k}{k^2}$ is absolutely summable. If $X$ were complete, this series would converge in $X$. Let's show that this is not the case.

Now, by absurd, assume that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{k^2}$ converges to a vector $x$. Since $\left\{b_k\right\}$ is a basis, we can write $x=\sum_{i=k}^n\alpha_kb_k$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and numbers $\alpha_i$. Notice that $$0=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k b_k=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}-\alpha_k\right)b_k+\sum_{k=n+1}^N\frac{b_k}{k^2}\right),$$
and, by the definition of the norm, all the terms (partial sums) in the right side of the equation above have norm $\geq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}>0$, an absurd.

Therefore, $X$ is incomplete.